# realloc() invalid old size

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am doing an exercise for fun from KandR C programming book. The program is for finding the longest line from a set of lines entered by the user and then prints it.

Here is what I have written (partially, some part is taken from the book directly):-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MAXLINE =  10;
int INCREMENT = 10;

void copy(char longest[], char line[]){
    int i=0;

    while((longest[i] = line[i]) != '\0'){
        ++i;
    }
}

int _getline(char s[]){
    int i,c;

    for(i=0; ((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'); i++){
        if(i == MAXLINE - 1){
            s = (char*)realloc(s,MAXLINE + INCREMENT);

            if(s == NULL){
                printf("%s","Unable to allocate memory");
                //  goto ADDNULL;
                exit(1);
            }

            MAXLINE = MAXLINE + INCREMENT;
        }
        s[i] = c;
    }

    if(c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

ADDNULL:
    s[i]= '\0';
    return i;
} 

int main(){
    int max=0, len;

    char line[MAXLINE], longest[MAXLINE];

    while((len = _getline(line)) > 0){
        printf("%d", MAXLINE);
        if(len > max){
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }

    if(max>0){
        printf("%s",longest);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The moment I input more than 10 characters in a line, the program crashes and displays:-

```
*** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid old size: 0x00007fff26502ed0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3d6a07bbe7]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3d6a07f177]
/lib64/libc.so.6(realloc+0xd2)[0x3d6a0805a2]
./a.out[0x400697]
./a.out[0x40083c]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x3d6a021b45]
./a.out[0x400549]
```

I also checked [realloc invalid old size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406311/realloc-invalid-old-size) but could not follow the logic of passing a pointer to a pointer to the function modifying the array.

Comment: Amongst other errors in the program (use parens to assure meaning in calculations and elsewhere) the program is writing 'int' size values to the 's' array, but only allocating char size increments.

Comment: The function name '_getline' will conflict with the C library function name.  rather use something like 'myGetLine'

Comment: The parameter passed to _getline is NOT a pointer to a malloc'd area, rather it the first address of an area on the stack.  Therefore, trying to realloc() that pointer is an error.  Suggest getting initial pointer for the _getline parameter as "line = (MAXSIZE*sizeof(int));"

Comment: When performing the realloc, use a second parameter of ((MAXLINE + INCREMENT)*sizeof(int))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`realloc` call will re-allocate memory by taking a pointer to a storage area on the `heap`  i.e a dynamically allocated memory result of a call to `malloc`.

In your case the problem is that you are allocating memory on the `stack` and not dynamically by a call to `malloc` which results memory allocation on the `heap`. And, passing the pointer of the `automatic` character array `line` to `_getline` which uses it for call to `realloc`. So, you got the error.

Try dynamically allocating the character array `line` :

```
char* line  = (char *) malloc(MAXLINE); 
char* longest = ( char *) malloc(MAXLINE);
```

Comment: So then my _getline function would be something like _getline(char* s)?

Comment: @Karan, no keep the `_getline` as it is, in `C` array `names` are automatically `decayed` to the pointers to their first elements.

Comment: @Karan, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying for array decaying.

Comment: Thanks. However, on large inputs, i get another error related to realloc: *** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000009ce010 ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @Karan, Segmentation faults are common in C and occurs when you allocate less size than your input. In the problem context you are allocating less memory on the heap and trying to overwrite memory from the large buffer data you entered so you are getting the error.See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault for more.

Answer (score 6):

You get an `invalid old size` error when your code writes the memory that `malloc`/`realloc` allocated for "housekeeping information". This is where they store the "old" allocated size. This also happens when the pointer that you pass to `realloc` has not been properly initialized, i.e. it's neither a `NULL` nor a pointer previously returned from `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

In your case, the pointer passed to `realloc` is actually an array allocated in automatic memory - i.e. it's not a valid pointer. To fix, change the declarations of `line` and `longest` as follows:

```
char *line = malloc(MAXLINE), *longest = malloc(MAXLINE);
```

To avoid memory leaks, make sure that you call `free(line)` and `free(longest)` at the end of your program.

Answer (score 1):

if `_getline()` reads 10 or more characters, it will call `realloc()` on memory that was not allocated with `malloc()`. This is **undefined behavior**.

Additionally, the memory allocated from `realloc()` will be leaked at the end of the call to `_getline()`.

Additionally, let's assume that the input string is `"0123456789\n"`. Then you will attempt to write to `longest` that value, but you will **never** call `realloc()` before you do that, which is required.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `realloc()` memory that was not allocated dynamically with `malloc()`.  You cannot do that.

Also, if `realloc()` fails, the original memory is still allocated, and thus still needs to be freed with `free()`.  So do not assign the return value of `realloc()` to the original pointer unless it is not NULL, otherwise you are leaking the original memory.  Assign the return value of `realloc()` to a temp variable first, check its value, and then assign to the original pointer only if `realloc()` was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
int _getline(char s[])
```

It means `_getline` is a function returning `int` getting a pointer to `char` by value.

You actually want to pass that pointer (which **must point to memory allocated with `malloc()` or be `NULL`**) by reference.

That means, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer to `char`.

Correcting that error will force you to correct all follow-on errors too.

Only use `free` / `realloc` on `NULL` resp. on pointers returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` or a function specified to return such a pointer.