# realloc: invalid next size and malloc: memory corruption (fast)

Tags: c, realloc

I am doing an exercise for fun from K and R C programming book. The program is for finding the longest line from a set of lines entered by the user and then prints it.

#### Inputs:

```
This is a test

This is another long test

this is another long testthis is another long test
```

#### Observation:

It runs fine for the first two inputs but fails for the larger string (3rd input)

#### Errors:

```
Error in `./longest': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x000000000246e010 ***
Error in `./longest': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x000000000246e030 ***
```

#### My efforts:

I have been trying to debug this since 2 days (rubber duck debugging) but the logic seems fine. GDB points to the realloc call in the _getline function and shows a huge backtrace with glibc.so memory allocation calls at the top.

Here is what I have written (partially, some part is taken from the book directly):-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MAXLINE =  10;
int INCREMENT = 10;

char* line = NULL, *longest = NULL;

void _memcleanup(){
    free(line);
    free(longest);      
}

void copy(char longest[], char line[]){
    int i=0;
    char* temp = realloc(longest,(MAXLINE)*sizeof(char));
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("%s","Unable to allocate memory");
        _memcleanup();
        exit(1);
    }
    longest = temp;

    while((longest[i] = line[i]) != '\0'){
        ++i;
    }    
}

int _getline(char s[]){
  int i,c;
  for(i=0; ((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'); i++){
    if(i == MAXLINE - 1){
      char* temp = realloc(s,(MAXLINE + INCREMENT)*sizeof(char));
      if(temp == NULL){
        printf("%s","Unable to allocate memory");
        _memcleanup();
        exit(1);
      }

      s= temp;
      MAXLINE += INCREMENT;
    }
    s[i] = c;
  }

  if(c == '\n'){
      s[i++] = c;
  }

  s[i]= '\0';

  return i;
} 

int main(){
  int max=0, len;

  line = malloc(MAXLINE*sizeof(char));
  longest = malloc(MAXLINE*sizeof(char));

  while((len = _getline(line)) > 0){
    printf("%d%d", len, MAXLINE);
    if(len > max){
      max = len;
      copy(longest, line);
    }
  }
  if(max>0){
    printf("%s",longest);
  }

  _memcleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think may need `if(i == MAXLINE - 2){` in `_getline()`.

Comment: When `i == MAXLINE - 2`, no realloc occurs.  If the next `getchar()`, now with `i == MAXLINE - 1`, is a `'\n'`, loop ends and `s[MAXLINE - 1] = '\n';`.  _Then_ `s[MAXLINE]= '\0';`, which is UB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [realloc() invalid old size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579698/realloc-invalid-old-size)

Comment: On a side note, I spent about 30 seconds thinking that `MAXLINE` was a constant.  Best to not name variables like constants or macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You´re reallocating on copied addresses (because parameters).
A parameter in C is a copy of the original value everytime; in case of
a pointer it will point to the same location but the address itself is copied.

`realloc` resizes the buffer asociated with the address, everything fine so far.
But it can relocate the whole thing and assign a completely new address,
and this new address (if it happens) will be lost after the function returns to main.

Use a double pointer:
Pass a `char **s` instead of `char *s` (==`char s[]`) as formal parameter,
pass `&xyz` intead of `xyz` as actual value, and inside the function,
use `*xyz` and `**xyz` (or `(*xyz)[index]`) for address and value.

Other things:
Global variables are ugly (and confusing when named same as parameters),
multiplying with `sizeof(char)` is nonsense because it´s be 1 everytime,
and names in capitals should be used for `#define`´s rather than variables.

Comment: How do i avoid ugly global variables? My situation is that i need to call free from multiple functions on the same set of pointers.

Comment: Well, make the variable in main and pass it as parameter. If you include the double pointer stuff and add (poimter) to int for the to numbers, copy is already OK...

Answer (score 3):

The double pointer alone, isn't the solution to your problems. You have 2 primary issues. You can see them by entering your strings as a string of characters and will notice you problem occurs when you pass the 20th character. (e.g. `01234567890123456789`)

You have declared both `line` and `longest` globally. So while you can rewrite `_getline (char **s)`, you can also simply update `line` at the end of `_getline` with `memcpy` (include `string.h`). For example:

```
    memcpy (line, s, (size_t)i);

    return i;
}
```

That cures your `_getline` issue. Issue two is fairly straight forward. You are not null-terminating `longest` in `copy`. (your choice of arguments with the same name as the globals presents challenges as well) Including the following fixes copy:

```
        ++i;
    }

    longest[i] = '\0';
}
```

If you incorporate both changes, then I believe you will find you routine works. You can then rewite `_getline (char **s)` and pass `&line` as another exercise. For example, you can rewrite `_getline` as:

```
int
_getline (char **s) {
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; ((c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n'); i++) {
        if (i == MAXLINE - 1) {
            char *temp = realloc (*s, (MAXLINE + INCREMENT) * sizeof (char));
            if (temp == NULL) {
                printf ("%s", "Unable to allocate memory");
                _memcleanup ();
                exit (1);
            }
            *s = temp;
            MAXLINE += INCREMENT;
        }
        (*s)[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
        (*s)[i++] = c;
    }

    (*s)[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

And then modify your call in main to:

```
while ((len = _getline (&line)) > 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the thanks. I knew you had a headache with this one because I nearly pulled my hair out as well :)